# Cannot hide the URL bar in a TWA gatsby react app on Android

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, gatsby

I have my app pushed out currently to google play.  However when I download and install, the url bar still shows on the app.

Steps I've taken to solve this with no changes:

1. I realized I was using the upload certificate in my assetlinks.json, so I copied and pasted the app signing certificate from my google play console in it instead.
2. In my manifest.webmanifest file, I was using `display: 'minimal-ui'` in my gatsby-config.js file, so I changed it to `display: 'standalone'` and rebuilt the project, allowing the change to carry over to the manifest.webmanifest file.

Still no change.  When I run the app in Lighthouse audit, the simulator doesn't show a URL bar, but it does on my phone when I install it.  Anything else to try?

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: I'm thinking it may be a cache issue from my cloudfront.  My changes I made above still aren't being reflected.  I'll check again later after it refreshes.